# Reason why RPi4 is unstable when oveclocking over 1500 MHz

Tags: pi-4, overclocking

I'm trying to OC my RPi4 to 2 GHz, but anything above 1.5 GHz seems to make my pi unstable and unusable.

This is my config

```
...

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

over_voltage=6
arm_freq=1600
gpu_freq=600
```

Why is this happening?

I've read about the "silicon lottery", but am I missing something here?

If I decide to get a new Pi, how would I even know that I can OC it?

Edit: My question is not opinion based. I'm not asking for opinions. I'm asking for answers why I can not OC my Pi.

It's not an opinion:able question, there has to be technical answer to it.

Comment: you mentioned "silicon lottery", so you already know the answers to your questions ... why are you asking, if you already know the answer?

Comment: @jsotola because: "... but am I missing something here?"

Comment: And I akso asked: "... how would I even know that I can OC it?"

Comment: @jsotola and just because I mention "silicon lottery" does not mean that I know what it implies. Unless you're going to have a dialog with me, why even bother asking Me questions.

Comment: i misunderstood about your knowledge then ... my apologies ... the processor manufacturing process is not a 100% exact science ... there are variations between the finished product ... some of them will run reliably at higher clock speeds, while others will not ... the manufacturer may test the chips at 1.5 GHz, 2.0 GHz, and so on and then sell them as being reliable at a specific speed ... a 1.5 GHz chip may actually be reliable up to 2.0 GHz, but it could also not be reliable much above 1.5 GHz just as easily, hence the term "silicon lottery"

Comment: @jsotola No problems. Aaaah I see. So it's more or less a hit and miss for me as the consumer, right? If I'd want to acquire an OC:able Pi 4B, I'd just have to buy a bunch and hope that at least one of them meet my requirement, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi Foundation does not guarantee speeds above the default 1.5GHz. Due to varying silicon qualities, some processors will overclock more than others. This is what the 'silicon lottery' is. So some processors will overclock to 2.147GHz, others 1.8GHz, or some might not even reach past 1.5GHz, like yours.

So it looks like you've lost the silicon lottery.